How do I format this richTextBox text?
I am building an app to suggest dates (romantic dates, not almenac dates) based on inputs by the user. In the end, I want to output the inputs into a richTextBox and format it to look something like:

Your date:
blablablablabla

Now all posts I've seen about this talk about formatting text you can predict. I would like to be able to make a string and format it then and there like:
string text = "**Your Date:**\nblablablablabla";

Is there any way to do this? Since I can't format specific bits of text when I don't know what the text will be.

There are lots of examples of colouring text in a RichTextBox around and that's basically how you do it for any formatting. You programmatically select the text in the control and then you set the SelectionFont or whatever.

You can format any text any way you want in C#, and that includes Dates. See String.Format Method and StringBuilder Class.

I thought I clarified with examples. I don't want to color the text, i want to make it bold. Also I don't know how to select text that is randomly placed and not in the same place every time. It's not going to be fixed output, it's going to change, and I need to be able to make some pieces of it bold and other not

Color or style are just font properties. No difference. The start and end or length of the selection is what you need to keep track of. We can't help since we don't know what and how you add the data. Note all formatting is part of the rtb.Text, not of the strings you add.

The answer depends on whether you are adding the formatted text to the RichTextBox, or formatting existing text. For adding to the end you'll use RichTextBox.AppendText. For replacing formatted text, use property RichtTextBox.SelectedText`
First of all, it is good to create a method that parses the string to format into pieces that have just one format. Something like this:
class TextToFormat
{
    public System.Drawing.FontStyle FontStyle {get; set;} // bold, italic, underscore, etc
    public string Text {get; set;}
}


If you want more formatting than simple FontStyles as bold / underline / etc, consider to add properties like Color and Size to TextToFormat;

You need a method that converts your input string into a sequence of TextToFormat. I write it as an extension method of class string. If you are not familiar with extension methods, consider to read Extension Methods Demystified.
static IEnumerable<TextToFormat> ToTextToFormat(this string txt)
{
    ...     // TODO: implement
}

Usage would be:
string text = "**Your Date:**\nblablablablabla";
IEnumerable<TextToFormat> textToFormat = text.ToTextToFormat();

Expected output:
IEnumerable<TextToFormat> textToFormat = new
    {
        FontStyle = FontStyle.Bold,
        Text = "Your Date:",
    },
    {
        FontStyle = FontStyle.Regular,
        Text = "\nblablablablabla",
    },
}

The implementation depends the definition of how you define bold, italic, etc, in your example you use double asterisks for bold. You'll need a definition for the other FontStyle and an escape character.
This implementation not simple, I think you need to build a one symbol look ahead top down parser (is this still a used software term?). Consider to reuse existing software for this, or to use some standard formatting.

Come to think of it, if you are generating your text with the asterisks etc from some separate fields, wouldn't it be easier to generate the sequence of TextToFormat directly instead of using a string with format codes?

As soon as you have found a string with some formatting code:
FontStyle foundStyle = ... // for example FontSyle.Bold
string foundText = ...     // for example "Your Date:"

yield return new TextToFormat
{
    Format = foundFormat;
    Text = foundText;
}

Anyway, once you have the method to create a sequence of TextToFormat, it is time to extend the RichTextBox with some extension methods:
public static void Add(this RichTextBox richTextBox, 
                       IEnumerable<TextToFormat> textsToFormat)
{
    foreach (TextToFormat textToFormat in textsToFormat)
    {
        richTextBox.Add(textToFormat);
    }
}

public static void Add(this RichTextBox richTextBox, TextToFormat textToFormat)
{

    richTextBox.Add(FontStyle fontStyle, textToFormat.Text);
}

Now some basic extension methods for RichTextBox
public static void Add(his RichTextBox richTextBox, FontStyle fontStyle, string text)
{
    richTextBox.Font.Style = fontStyle;
    richTextBox.AppendText(text);
}

If you don't want to influence the font of the richTextBox, don't forget to change it back to the original font:
var originalFontStyle = richTextBox.Font.Style;
richTextBox.Font.Style = fontStyle;
richTextBox.AppendText(text);
richTextBox.Font.Style = originalFontStyle;

If you added font color and font size to TextToFormat
richTextBox.ForeColor = fontColor;
richTextBox.Font.Size = fontSize;
richTextBox.Font.Style = fontStyle;
richTextBox.AppendText(text);

